# Multer set Dynamic destination based on type

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I've an API that handle file Upload using *Multer* in my ExpressJS.
Here is my code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage(
    {
      destination : path.join(pathStorage + pathIdCard),
      filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
      }
    }
);

const upload = multer({
  storage : storage
}).single('image');

router.post('/upload-image', function(req, res){
  try {
    upload(req, res, err => {
      responseUtil.success(res, obj);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    responseUtil.fail(res, 'Upload image failed!')
  }
});
```

The code above is work well, but the code above only work for One destination. I want to make the destination based on property called `type`.

I only have two type:
1. ID-Card,
2. Selfie.

So if the type is ID-Card, the destination should be `pathStorage + pathIdCard`, but if the type is selfie then the destination should be `pathStorage + pathSelfie`.

I've tried following answer from another issue in SO but nothing work for me.

Here is my Req example using postman:
[image]

Comment: "I've tried following answer from another issue in SO but nothing work for me." - Can you give additional context regarding what did you try and what does it mean to nothing works? otherwise, someone will come and recommend that same solution to you.

Comment: You can pass a function to the `destination` argument in which you could check the type.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem today but maybe this will help you with yours.
I wanted to pass a dynamic path for the uploaded file to be safed. I passed my dynamic path in the request header and went on from there...

You could pass the type in the headers and depending on this you could set the right path.

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
      let path;
      if(req.headers.type === 'ID_TYPE') {
        path = pathStorage + pathIdCard;  
      } else {
        path = pathStorage + pathSelfie;
      }
      callback(null, path);
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
  })
});
```

Hope this helps you out!